# Keycloak Infinispan cache replication is not working

Tags: keycloak, infinispan

Infinispan isn't replicating caches across the cluster; the user is asked to login again when Keycloak on any node in the cluster isn't healthy. Can you please help point out what we are doing wrong?

We followed the documentation for Keycloak Infinispan setup (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#sticky-sessions) and set the owners for all caches to 3. Below is an example excerpt of our cache owner setup (domain/configuration/domain.xml)

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:11.0">
   <cache-container name="keycloak">
       <distributed-cache name="sessions" owners="3"/>
...
```

Details about our Keycloak setup

- Domain clustered mode
- 1 primary, 2 secondary
- Hosted on AWS and ALB has sticky session enabled.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like it's not clustering together, the nodes can't discover each other - that would be a JGroups configuration issue. Check logs if there's something along the lines of 'Received new view' that lists all nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We verified this and the jgroupsping table has been created in postgres to facilitate the discovery of the other nodes in the cluster.

Comment: One thing is that the nodes are discoverable, another is if it really manages to form the cluster. Without logs you won't get much better answer.

Comment: `2021-08-20 00:47:48,381 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [node1, [node2]` i have the same case, but when i restart one node, all user sessions on that node are removed and require user to login again